# Calling Activity from Class

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

In my application, there is an `Activity` class and a helper class. Activity class has access to a `TextView` which displays the score. Helper class needs to periodically update score in the activity class.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
  TextView textView;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Helper helper = new Helper();
  }

  void updateScore(int score)
  {
    textView.setText(score + "");
  }

  /* ... */
}

public class Helper
{
  int score = 0;

  void updateScore()
  {
    // what to do here?
  }
}
```

I found two ways to do this but they are not very good. One way is to pass activity instance to helper class. Other way is to declare `TextView` static. However, both are susceptible to memory leaks. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: If you are continuously updating score to Activity then a Callback(Interface) will be better it will also work for your context problem.

Comment: You can use data binding here to directly reflect your model properties on the view. You can follow: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDatabinding/article.html

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using interface

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MainActivity.Callback {
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        Helper helper = new Helper(this);
    }

    @Override
    void updateScore(int score) {
        textView.setText(score + "");
    }

    interface Callback {
        void updateScore(int score);
    }

    /* ... */
}

public class Helper {
    int score = 0;
    Callback callback;

    public Helper(Callback callback){
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    void updateScore() {
        callback.updateScore(score);
    }
}
```

When you call updateScore from helper class, it will call the updateScore from activity and pass the score to it and you can update the TextView inside MainActivity.